# Why are the arguments for substring functions mismatched?

Tags: language-agnostic, language-design, strings

In many languages, the substring function works like this:

substring(startIndex, endIndex)

returns the substring from startIndex until endIndex-1 (if you view startIndex and endIndex as 0-based) / from startIndex+1 to endIndex (1-based)

This is confusing. I understand that the two parameters can be interpreted as "startIndex" and "length of the substring", but in my opinion that is still confusing and even in this case, startIndex is 0-based while length is 1-based.

Why not stick to one convention for both the function arguments? and why do  newer languages like ruby and python continue to stick to this standard?

Comment: length = endIndex - startIndex

Comment: Also, to get the tail end of a string: `tail = str.substring(startIndex, str.length)`

Comment: This isn't really language agnostic. In many languages the second parameter is `length` and not `endIndex`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second argument is *not* the "length of the substring", that only works if you start at the very beginning of the string. The point is that specifying "from".."to" is linguistically ambiguous: you name two limit values, but do you want those two values themselves included in the extracted range or not?
In normal parlance, there isn't a strong conventional preference: "I knew her from first to fourth grade" means "for four years", but "training is from one to three" means "two hours", not three.

Therefore, it would be a major source of confusion if the indices referred to *characters* in a string. What they really refer to is the *positions between the characters*: 0 means "before the string", 1 means "after the first character", 2 means "after the second character" etc. Therefore, `s.substring(0,2)` means "The first two characters of s", unambiguously. (The fact that `endIndex - startIndex == length(extract)` is admittedly a nice bonus.)

Comment: "Therefore, it would be a major source of confusion if the indices referred to characters in a string." Would it? I don't see why it would be any more ambiguous than referring to the "positions between the characters".

Comment: Ranges are indeed ambiguous in general. But that's what conventions and documentation are for. For instance, ranges in Python are *always* half-open.

Answer (score 2):

There are [reasons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110804/why-are-zero-based-arrays-the-norm) why Python and Ruby use the convention you describe.  These reasons may not be immediately evident -- but experience, and reasoned [explanations](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF) ([transcribed](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html)) by well-respected language designers, give good reason to think that zero-based, half-open array ranges are the least error-prone of many possible options.

@KilianFoth's answer gives a common and useful mnemonic for visualizing and using this convention.  But the reason newer languages use the convention is because it works.

Answer (score 1):

For situations where [3,6] would mean the third, fourth, and fifth characters, but not the sixth, I would suggest that it may be helpful to imagine the characters as occupying space on a number line, with indices representing points between the characters.  The first character would sit in the space between 0 and 1, the next between 1 and 2, then 2..3, etc.  The range [3,6] would include the spaces from 3..4, 4..5, and 5..6.  By convention, using just a single subscript *n* will refer to the range (*n*)..*(n*+1).

Viewed in this fashion, it becomes clear that [3,6] and [6,8] refer to two touching but not overlapping ranges of characters, since they occupy touching but non-overlapping space on the number line.